# Get property value from MemberExpression

Tags: c#, expression

I'm attempting to retrieve the value of a property from an instance of `MemberExpression`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
protected override void VisitMember(Context context, MemberExpression node)
{              
    var propertyInfo = node.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if(propertyInfo != null)
    {
       var v = propertyInfo.GetValue(node.Member , null);
       val = Convert.ToString(v);
    }
    context.State.Append(val);
}
```

Depending on the approach I take there are two problems: I don't know the expected type (string, int, etc...), and/or I have not been able access the instance from the `MemberExpression`.

I am writing a small lambda expressions to T-SQL converter. For example `(u)=> u.FirstName == u.LastName;` would convert to `FirstName = 'chuck'`. I've almost got it working!

**update**

I tried the following code:

```
...  

var propertyInfo = node.Member as PropertyInfo;

if(propertyInfo != null)
{
   var o = propertyInfo.GetValue(node.Expression, null);
}

...
```

It did not work. I get the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException : Object does not match target type.
```

**update 2**

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
    public static Func<T, object> GetValueGetter<T>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
        var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
        var convert = Expression.TypeAs(property, typeof(object));
        return (Func<T, object>)Expression.Lambda(convert, instance).Compile();
    }
```

But I do not know `T` at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know the expected type (string, int, etc...),

Use [`Expression.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.type.aspx)

> I have not been able access the instance from the MemberExpression

Use [`MemberExpression.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.expression.aspx) - obviously that's another expression, because you might have:

```
foo.GetBar(20).ToString().Length
```

in which case the `Length` property would be a `MemberExpression`, but the `Expression` property would give the `MethodCallExpression` for `ToString`.

Comment: All the examples I have seen cast with a Func<T, object> (i.e. '(Func<T, object>)Expression.Lambda(convert, instance).Compile();') which is a cast with a generic. Generics are of course compile time...

Comment: ... my issue is, I don't know the type until runtime.

Comment: @ChuckConway: In that case you don't want a generic method, you just want something returning `Expression`, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not been able access the instance from the MemberExpression.

In your example `u => u.FirstName == "chuck"`, there is no instance for which to fetch the `FirstName` property.

I think you *actually* want the name of the property - which is `node.Member.Name` (and is "FirstName" in your example). Note that this works for all `MemberInfo`, not just `PropertyInfo`, so fields will work as well. (You may want to test anyway, because Events are also member expressions, but don't make sense here.)

> I don't know the expected type (string, int, etc...),

The expected type is either `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` or `FieldInfo.FieldType`.

Comment: There is, it's passed in as the MemberExpression parameter. MemberExpresion is `u.FirstName`. I'm not looking for the name of the property. I'm seeking the value of the property.

Comment: But in a lambda expression there is no instance for which to pull the value of the property from, unless you provide it somewhere else. `u => u.FirstName` will only have an instance on which to get the value when you actually call it on some object.

Comment: That makes sense. Most example I have seen are compiling the lambda expression before retrieving the property value. In these cases the type is known at compile time. In my case I do not know the type.

Comment: If you're converting `u => u.FirstName == "chuck"` to `FirstName = 'chuck'` you shouldn't need the value of the property anyway, only the name of the property - that's why I showed how to do that.

Comment: ahh, good point. I updated the question. I'm trying to cover this scenerio: `u => u.FirstName == u.LastName` to `FirstName = 'chuck'` where the right hand evalution is converted to the value of the property. The leftside is the name of the property.

Comment: You have the same problem here... when you look at the Expression for  `u.LastName` there's no instance to fetch a value from.

Comment: @ChuckConway: Your update #2 changes things quite a bit :) If you don't know `T` at compile time, then you won't be able to return a typed `Func<T,object>` - would it be possible to return a simple `Delegate` (returned by `.Compile()`) instead? It depends on what you're doing with the result of that function...